# MacOSのcronまたはlaunchdでgdateが正しく動かない

Tags: macos, shellscript, cron

MacOS 10.14.6 上で以下のようなシェルスクリプトをcronとlaunchdで実行させてみたのですが、gdateで期待しない値が返ってきました。
コンソールからシェルスクリプトをマニュアルで実行した場合は期待通りの値が返ってきます。

cronまたはlaunchdでgdateから期待通りの値を取得する方法をご存知でしたらご教示いただけないでしょうか。

### date_cron.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

gdate_hour=`gdate -d '3 hours ago' +'%H'`
date_hour=`date +'%H'`

echo "gdate_hour=${gdate_hour}" > result.txt
echo "date_hour=${date_hour}" >> result.txt
```

### result.txtに書き込まれた内容

#### cronまたはlaunchdで11時台に実行した場合

```
gdate_hour=
date_hour=11
```

#### コンソールからマニュアルでシェルスクリプトを実行した場合

```
gdate_hour=08
date_hour=11
```

なお、crontabおよびlaunchdの設定内容は以下の通りです。

#### crontab

```
*/1 * * * * cd /Users/hoge; /bin/sh date_cron.sh
```

#### launchd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>date_cron</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/sh</string>
        <string>/Users/hoge/date_cron.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>60</integer>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/Users/hoge</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/hoge/date_cron.out</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/hoge/date_cron.err</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: date_cron.shのgdateを完全パス名に変えたら振る舞いはどうなりますか？

Comment: 絶対パスに変更したら期待通りに動作しました！ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CRONで実行する場合、ログイン時の設定は読み込まれません。
今回のケースはgdateのパスが通っていなかったようです。
CRONで実行するコマンドやCRONで実行されるスクリプト内で起動するコマンドを完全パス名で記述すると、パスが通っていないコマンドでも実行できます。

コマンドによっては環境変数によって挙動が変わるものもあるので、起動するスクリプトで明示的に設定を読み込む必要があるかもしれません。